# StreamSocket to Stream in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, stream, bluetooth, windows-phone-8

I am trying to use Bluetooth in WP8 to send an image from my app on a device and show it in my app on another device. The receiver has a StreamSocket object to read the data from it like the code below

```
await _dataReader.LoadAsync(4);
uint messageLen = (uint)_dataReader.ReadInt32();
await _dataReader.LoadAsync(messageLen);
string imageData _dataReader.ReadString(messageLen);
```

Then I have to save all the received data (image) on the device and then create a Stream object from the stored data to give it to the BitmapSource.SetSource(Stream) function to be able to show this image on my app.

```
var image = new BitmapImage();
image.SetSource(stream);
```

All I want to do is not to skip this double work and directly convert the StreamSocket object (from Bluetooth connection) to a Stream object and make the BitmapSource image. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: The StreamSocket type object will have an input stream property

Comment: This InputStream ([link](http://This%20InputStream%20%5Blink%5D%28http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.iinputstream%29%20property)) property can not be converted to Stream([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.io.stream(v=vs.105).aspx)) class object.

Comment: Show some code of what you have tryed so far, please

Comment: Using this code is receive the data

            `await _dataReader.LoadAsync(4);
            uint messageLen = (uint)_dataReader.ReadInt32();
            await _dataReader.LoadAsync(messageLen);
            return _dataReader.ReadString(messageLen);`

Then I save the data returned by this function in a file and then open it again on a stream object and execute this part of code

            `var image = new BitmapImage();
            image.SetSource(stream);
            return image;`

The result is image. But I want to skip saving image on device and reading it again.

Comment: Add it to the question, in order to make it more legible. The more info you put in the question, more likely will you be to get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo can store the data received in a `byte[]` buffer and then create the stream from it. Try the following:

```cs
    await _dataReader.LoadAsync(4); 
    uint messageLen = (uint)_dataReader.ReadInt32();
    await _dataReader.LoadAsync(messageLen); 
    byte[] buffer = new byte[messageLen];
    _dataReader.ReadBytes(buffer);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer);
    var image = new BitmapImage();
    image.SetSource(ms);
```